# ant checksum directory does not reflect removed files

Tags: ant, checksum

I have the following ant targets defined. The idea is to do the heavy work only, if some contents of a folder have changed.

```
<target name="checksumAssets">
    <echo message="verify checksums" />

    <checksum todir="${bin.loc}/../checksums"  verifyproperty="checksum.isUpToDate.test">
        <fileset dir="${bin.loc}/assets/" id="filelist">
            <include name="somefolder/" />
            <exclude name="somefolder/result.swf"/>
        </fileset>
    </checksum>
    <echo message="${toString:filelist}"/>
    <echoproperties regex="checksum.isUpToDate.test"/>
</target>

<target name="createAsset" depends="checksumAssets" unless="${checksum.isUpToDate.test}">

    <!-- do create the assets and other magic -->

    <echo message="create checksum files" />
    <checksum todir="${bin.loc}/../checksums" >
        <fileset refid="filelist" />
    </checksum>
</target>
```

somefolder contains images which will be processed and result in a swf file containing these assets.

i want this heavy processing only to take place if something in the asset folder changes.

#### this works as espected in two cases:

- i add a new file to somefolder
- i change an existing file in somefolder

### my problem is:

- it does not work when i delete a file from this folder.

this means, the createAsset Target is not called on `ant createAsset` if i remove a file from the folder in question. it is called in the two aforementioned cases and if there are no checksum files present in the checksums folder.

is there something i missed?

ant version is 1.8.2

Comment: btw. this is unrelated to the format="" attribute. it does not work with md5 nor md5sum.

Answer (score 0):

i've found a workaround.

since `<checksum>` only saves the checksum of single files, it cannot know if a file is missing from a previous run. for this it would need to save the checksum of a complete filelist on disk.

this is what i accomplished:

```
<target name="checksumAssets">
    <echo message="verify checksums" />

    <!-- generate filelist.txt with actual content of somefolder -->
    <fileset dir="${bin.loc}/assets/somefolder/" id="filelist">
        <exclude name="result.swf"/>
        <exclude name="filelist.txt"/>
    </fileset>
    <concat destfile="${bin.loc}/assets/somefolder/filelist.txt" fixlastline="true">${toString:filelist}</concat>

    <!-- checksum folder including the filelist.txt -->
    <checksum todir="${bin.loc}/../checksums"  verifyproperty="checksum.isUpToDate.test">
        <fileset dir="${bin.loc}/assets/" id="checkedlist">
            <include name="somefolder/" />
            <exclude name="somefolder/result.swf"/>
        </fileset>
    </checksum>
</target>

<target name="createAsset" depends="checksumAssets" unless="${checksum.isUpToDate.test}">

    <!-- do create the assets and other magic -->

    <echo message="create checksum files" />
    <checksum todir="${bin.loc}/../checksums" >
        <fileset refid="checkedlist" />
    </checksum>
</target>
```

- first i generate a `filelist.txt` with the content of the current folder.
- then i generate checksums of all files in this folder, including the filelist.txt

on every an run, filelist.txt will be generated and checked against the filelist.txt from the last successful run of `createAsset`.

now the `createAsset` target is run if a content file changes or if the content of this folder changes.

mission accomplished ;)